# How do I set up Google App Engine project that uses Task Queues and GWT?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt, google-cloud-platform

A lot of work I want to do involves long-running processes that I want to run on a hosted environment and provide a web interface for users to see the results of the long-running jobs.

I believe Google App Engine with its "modules" feature (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/) is a great service for this but I have been struggling to figure out how to set it up for this purpose (see [App Engine Modules with GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24210228/app-engine-modules-with-gwt), [Possible to use Google Modules with Google Plugin for Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23141302/possible-to-use-google-modules-with-google-plugin-for-eclipse), [How use Eclipse to develop Google Modules for Google Cloud?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23224623/how-use-eclipse-to-develop-google-modules-for-google-cloud)).  Someone may have been trying to do the same thing (see: [how to create gwt gae with app engine modules using google eclipse plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23259113/how-to-create-gwt-gae-with-app-engine-modules-using-google-eclipse-plugin)) but there's no accepted answer and I'm looking for a more comprehensive set of instructions.

Could someone provide a step-by-step set of instructions to set up the following Hello World project involving the following project architecture?

**Requirements**

- User visits web page and types in a job name, e.g. "Hello World" and their email address where they will receive the results.
- Google App Engine then performs a long-running computation (e.g. 10 hours, i.e. much longer than the 10 minute time limit for a module of Scaling Type "Automatic" as described here https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/).
- Google App Engine then sends an email to the user stating that the "Hello World" computation is finished and provides the result in the body of the email message.

**Project Architecture**

- Web front-end (ideally GWT but propose any suitable alternative since it may be a problem as described here: [App Engine Modules with GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24210228/app-engine-modules-with-gwt))
- Module 1 (Scaling Type = Automatic): Responds to web front-end requests by putting a job on a Google Task Queue with the name provided by the user.  The email address is recorded in the Google Datastore with a primary key equal to the job name (the purpose is I want to see how to make two modules share the same datastore; it's alluded to here: [Serving multiple GAE modules from one development server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22941772/serving-multiple-gae-modules-from-one-development-server/23024113) but I'd like to see more detail).
- Module 2 (Scaling Type = Basic Scaling): Picks up the job from the Google Task Queue, performs the long-running computation, and emails the result.  Note the email address is obtained by looking it up in the datastore using the job name.

**Development Environment**

- Google App Engine
- Java
- Google Modules (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/)
- Google Task Queues (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/queue)
- GWT
- Google Data Store (https://cloud.google.com/datastore/)
- Eclipse (Juno)
- Maven (via m2Eclipse plugin)
- Mac

Comment: Jarrod, thanks for the link to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759387/google-app-engine-task-queue-on-gwt. The additional complexity I'm grappling with is how to incorporate Google Modules, which didn't exist in 2009 when the similar question was asked.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your first module is a GWT app. It provides a user interface.
2. When a user initiates a request, you make a standard RPC call to one of your services within the same module. Within this service you crate a task using Task API. This task includes a [target parameter](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/queue#target) which points to your second module.

Alternatively, you can make a REST call directly to your second module.

3. Your second module is plain Java. It does not need GWT, and it's not a separate application in App Engine sense. It executes a task and emails the results to a user using App Engine [Mail API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/).

You do not need anything special in Eclipse to create this setup. You simply create a new directory called EAR in your existing project and create/copy a bunch of configuration files. [Modules Configuration](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/#Java_Configuration) provides detailed instructions on how to do it. If you are familiar with Backends, it may be easier to understand the process by reading [Converting backends to Modules](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/converting#Java_Converting_backends_to_Modules).

You can create two separate Eclipse projects - one per module, but it's not necessary. You can simply use a separate source directory for each module. For example, if you name your modules "gwtapp" and "backend" you can create the following packages in your project:

```
gwtapp.src.com.myproject...
backend.src.com.myproject...
```

Then open a build path (project Properties > Java Build Path), click on Source tab, then Add Folder. Add two folders:

```
gwtapp/src
backend/src
```

to your project. For each project select a different output folder: `gwtapp/src` will point to `MyProject/ear/gwtapp/war/WEB-INF/classes`, and `backend/src` will point to `MyProject/ear/backend/war/WEB-INF/classes`. You have to create these folders (`ear/gwtapp/war/WEB-INF` and `ear/backend/war/WEB-INF` respectively) before you do this step, of course.

Comment: Andrei, thank you for the help. Can the Google Plugin for Eclipse be used to create the GWT app?  And then do I add the EAR directory (etc.) to it?  I'm afraid not because of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23259113/how-to-create-gwt-gae-with-app-engine-modules-using-google-eclipse-plugin.  Am I better off creating the initial project using Maven?